# Is there a way to access TV audio?

Tags: android, webos, television

I'm currently fiddling around with an idea, and therefor I'm looking for a potential way to access the Audio-Stream on a TV (regardless if SmartTV, Android, WebOS, ...), run some audio-filters on it, and then have it output.

I've briefly read through some of the API's, but it seems I'm only able to control the volume - which is not really what I want. Am I missing something, or is this not possible at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

For webOS at the moment you can only:

1. setMuted
2. volumeDown
3. volumeUp

and the formats that can be supported it at the moment:

[image]

So you cannot change the audio from native side, the only way i can imagine for this to work is to use a js library or something similar that can be supported then make change and display it to users.

Reference:
http://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/api/webos-service-api/audio/